# ASP.NET Core Razor Page binding properties and preserve data in model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I have a question about model binding in razor pages .net core 3.1.  Lets say I have a model such as this:

```
    public Boolean bEmailMessages { get; set; }
    public string sUserEmail { get; set; }
    public Boolean bIcal { get; set; }
    public Boolean bEventNotice { get; set; }

    public string EPRLogin { get; set; }
    public string EPRPWD { get; set; }
    public string EPRLaunch { get; set; }
```

On one of my razor pages I use this model for only the top 4 items as inputs that are bound to those items.  In my constructor I am initializing this model with data from the database.  On my  HTTPPOST I get the model back, but the last 3 items are null (EPRLogin, EPRPWD, and EPRLaunch) because I have another page where the user updates those items.

Is there a way to preserve the data in that model and only have the binding update the data from the page?  The reason I ask, is because I have a function that I get the model from and I send it to save it to the database.

The only way I can think of doing this would be to get my model within the save method, change only the items I got back from the page model and then send my modified model to be saved.

I hope I explained this well enough...

Comment: Do you mean to get the first four items in the model first, and then transfer these four items to the update page, and there are three remaining items in the update page, and finally pass them to the database?

Comment: No.  I have a class like shown above, this is just a snip-it of data that is a users settings.  I have a razor page that binds this class (model) to the page as a property.  I have <input> fields all over the page that bind to the class (model) shown above.  But my class has other items that are not part of that page.  So, when I do a HttpPost back to the page, those <input> elements get bound back to my model.  The items that are not bound on the page are NULL.  I want to preserve those items not bound in my class (model).

Comment: Do you have a primary key like Id in your model?

Comment: No primary key.  I have a function that reads all the values from the database and fills in the model.  I basically save it like a dictionary in the database per user.  So, when the user logs in, I load these settings when needed.

Comment: I think you only need to query the model again in the post method, and then only update the first four items.

Comment: If you add a primary key to your model, the problem will become simple.

Comment: Hi @Bitco Software, any updates about this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, I think the best way is to update only the first four items. Below is a work demo.

You can add an Id into your model.

Then in your pagemodel(Assuming Id=1 is the initial value):

```
public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        Simple = _context.Simples.Find(1);
        return Page();
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost(Simple simple)
    {
        _context.Simples.Attach(simple);
        _context.Entry(simple).Property(x => x.bEmailMessages).IsModified = true;
        _context.Entry(simple).Property(x => x.bEventNotice).IsModified = true;
        _context.Entry(simple).Property(x => x.bIcal).IsModified = true;
        _context.Entry(simple).Property(x => x.sUserEmail).IsModified = true;
        _context.SaveChanges();
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }
        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
}
```

And your page:

```
<form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Simple.Id" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Simple.bEmailMessages" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Simple.bEmailMessages" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Simple.bEmailMessages" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Simple.bEventNotice" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Simple.bEventNotice" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Simple.bEventNotice" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Simple.bIcal" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Simple.bIcal" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Simple.bIcal" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Simple.sUserEmail" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Simple.sUserEmail" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Simple.sUserEmail" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

Result:
[image]